# Given a bunch of ranges of numbers, get all the numbers within those ranges?

Tags: python, algorithm

In Python, you can get the numbers in a range by calling `range(x,y)`. But given two ranges, say `5-15`, and `10-20` how can you get all the numbers `5-20` without duplicates? The ranges may also be disjoint.

I could concat all the results and then uniquify the list, but is that the fastest solution?

Comment: I'm a bit confused... What operation are you wanting?  "concatenating all the results and then uniquifying the list" wouldn't give you `10-20`.  Is there a typo in your question?

Comment: @Joe: Yes, there was. I meant `5-20`. By "concatenate" I meant `myuniquefunction(range(5,16)+range(10,21))` would give the result I wanted. (Added +1 to max to be inclusive).

Comment: How fast do you need it to be? Unless this is in the inner loop of some computation with lots of iterations, or the ranges are huge, then the answer given by @hughdbrown is sufficient, and pythonic to boot.

Comment: @Whatang: Yes, it looks sufficient. I'm not overly concerned about speed, it's more about elegance. I just don't like doing things that are multitudes slower than they need to be because I couldn't think of an elegant solution. Often there's a nice compact way to do it "nicely". I'll be combining up to 100 ranges, each range being up to about 50 in spread.

Comment: Can't you just check if the ranges overlap, and if they do, get the range from the lowest x to the highest y...?

Comment: @Pedery: There aren't always just going to be just 2 ranges.

Comment: Still, you could check all ranges against all the others, and for the cases where two ranges overlap, create a new longer range and discard the two overlapping ones.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
>>> a = range(5, 15)
>>> b = range(10, 20)
>>> print sorted(set(a + b))
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

Or if you want a more general expansion of the lists to their elements for inclusion in the set:

```
>>> list_of_lists = [a, b]
>>> print sorted(set(elem for l in list_of_lists for elem in l))
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

And I found a way to compose it all in one line:

```
>>> list_of_lists = [a, b]
>>> print set.union(*map(set, list_of_lists))
```

Is sorting necessary? It's just expository, but then I don't see that sets necessarily output in sorted order:

```
>>> x = set(range(3))
>>> x
set([0, 1, 2])
>>> x.add(-1)
>>> x
set([0, 1, 2, -1])
```

Comment: Ooh... I didn't think about using sets. Nice!

Comment: This solution is very nice and understandable. Not sure if it is fast or *the fastest*, but this shouldn't be the first worry at all.

Comment: @Mark - Also have a look at `set.union`, though if you're starting with lists, it's easiest to just "concatenate and uniquify". If you're doing something like calculating the union of multiple combinations of the same x number of lists, then it may make more sense to make them sets and use `union`.

Comment: In my tests, the set is always sorted. Is the call to `sorted` necessary?

Comment: @Joe: Yeah... just found that. I think I'm going to turn them into sets first and then union them together. Should be faster/use less memory than creating one giant list and then turning it into a set. I'm guessing, anyway.

Comment: @Mark, `set()` is being called with a generator expression, so no large temporary list is being constructed. I would be _very_ surprised if turning the lists into sets and taking the union would be faster.

Comment: @gnibbler: How is it using a generator expression? `range()` returns a list (`xrange` is a generator) and `a+b` concats them before they're even passed to the set? Or do you mean in the 2nd example? Yeah...I don't see any problems with that one.

Comment: @hughdbrown: `a = [1,2,3]; b = [4,5,6]; set(b+a)` returns `set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])`. It appears if you add multiple items at a time it will sort them, but if you add just one it won't. I'm guessing it's undefined behaviour and shouldn't be relied upon. `sorted` it is then. Thanks :D

Comment: @Mark, yes I meant the second one. The first one won't scale really well to 100 ranges

Answer (score 2):

Or you can join overlapping ranges:

```
>>> def join_overlapping_ranges(ranges):
...     list_of_ranges = []
...     # ranges are sorted on first element
...     for r in sorted(ranges):
...         # ranges are stored as [start, end]
...         if list_of_ranges and list_of_ranges[-1][1] >= r[0]:
...             list_of_ranges[-1][1] = r[1]
...         else:
...             list_of_ranges.append(r)        
...     return list_of_ranges
... 
>>> ranges = [[3,4], [5,7], [1,2], [4,6], [5,5]]
>>> print sorted(ranges)
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [4, 6], [5, 5], [5, 7]]
>>> print join_overlapping_ranges(ranges)
[[1, 2], [3, 7]]
```

Comment: Sounds like @IVlad's solution. Thanks for the implementation :)

Comment: This is a programming question used for interviewing at my current company. This is the expected answer, but the first I gave you is simpler to code and easier to understand, in my view.

Comment: Then why is this the expected answer? If speed isn't crucial, simplicity is usually better.

Answer (score 1):

Sort the ranges **(x, y)** by increasing **x** values. Now, for each range, if it overlaps the previous range, set your current "big range"'s **y** value to the current range's **y** value. If it doesn't, start a new "big range": this one won't overlap any of the previous ones. If the current range is completely included in the current big one, ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

For the quantity you need I would just keep it simple

```
>>> a = range(5, 15)
>>> b = range(10, 20)
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> sorted(set(chain.from_iterable(list_of_lists)))
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```